# webdriver параллельная работа с окнами одного хромдрайвера

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Хочу организовать работу с несколькими окнами параллельно с одного драйвера, но при любом обращении к объекту драйвера больше чем из одного потока, вылетает ошибка. Возможно ли вообще провернуть такой фокус?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
drive = "C:\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = drive
driver = webdriver.Chrome(drive)

class dv:
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
    def get(self):
        print self.driver.current_url

dvr = dv(driver)
t1 = Thread(target = lambda: dvr.get())
t2 = Thread(target = lambda: dvr.get())
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Даже если организовать строгую очередность доступа к драйверу через Queue, ситуация практически та же, в одном из потоков все равно вылетает ошибка

Comment: что за ошибка? Что мешает в каждом потоке свой браузер запустить?

Answer (score 0):

Вполне ожидаемая ошибка. Ты пытаешься работать с обьектом с первого потока с других потоков.

Тебе нужно работать с разными окнами не от одного инстанса драйвера, а с нескольких. Тогда проблема решится. Для каждого потока -- свой инстанс драйвера.